# Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'response

Tags: python, disnake

```py
await interaction.response.send_message(f'Проверьте: всё ли правильно написано, если нет, то снова введите команду `!description`.\nВаш текст: {prikol["service_description"]}', files=files_to_send, view=view, ephemeral=True)
```

выводит ошибку "`Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'response''`". Пытался заменить `response` на `followup`, `send_message` на просто `send`.. Но все равно результат один.

Если заменить `interaction.message.send_message` на `interaction.send` и не убрать параметр`ephemeral=True`, то будет новая ошибка: "`Command raised an exception: TypeError: Messageable.send() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ephemeral'`".

Команда, в которой используется данная строка:

```py
@bot.command(name="description")
async def desc(interaction: disnake.MessageInteraction, *args): # interaction: disnake.MessageInteraction
    global service_desc, picture_files
    prikol["service_description"] = " ".join(args)
    view = continue_button_class2()
    order_channel = bot.get_channel(1130092027942555740)

    if interaction.author != bot.user:
        if len(interaction.message.attachments) > 0 and interaction.message.content:
            picture_files = []
            unsupported_files = []

            for attachment in interaction.message.attachments:
                await attachment.save(os.path.join("cache", attachment.filename))
                if attachment.filename.lower().endswith((".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".gif")):
                    file = File(os.path.join("cache", attachment.filename))
                    picture_files.append(file)
                else:
                    unsupported_files.append(attachment.filename)

            if unsupported_files:
                await interaction.send("Формат следующих файлов не поддерживается: {}".format(", ".join(unsupported_files)))

            username = interaction.author.name
            file_count = 1

            for file in picture_files:
                filename, extension = os.path.splitext(file.filename)
                if username in filename:
                    for fake_file in os.listdir("cache"):
                        #filename, extension = os.path.splitext(file)
                        os.remove(os.path.join("cache", fake_file))
                new_filename = f"{username} ({file_count}){extension}"
                file.close()
                os.rename(os.path.join("cache", file.filename), os.path.join("cache", new_filename))
                file_count += 1

            files_to_send = []
            for filename in os.listdir("cache"):
                if username in filename:
                    with open(os.path.join("cache", filename), 'rb') as f:
                        file = disnake.File(f)
                        files_to_send.append(file)

            if files_to_send:
                await interaction.response.send_message(f'Проверьте: всё ли правильно написано, если нет, то снова введите команду `!description`.\nВаш текст: {prikol["service_description"]}',
                               files=files_to_send, view=view, ephemeral=True)
        elif interaction.message.content:
            await interaction.response.send_message(f'Проверьте: всё ли правильно написано, если нет, то снова введите команду `!description`.\nВаш текст: {prikol["service_description"]}',
                view=view, ephemeral=True)
```

Comment: ты весь скрипт собрался одной строкой написать? пеп8 грит что длина строки должна быть не более 80 символов.- вводи псевдопеременную тогда будет ясно на какой строке ошибка

Comment: Так это и есть строка, к которой относится ошибка. И это не весь скрипт, скрипт в котором используется эта строка имеет длину 50 строк, могу обновить вопрос добавив саму команду.

Comment: @ganz "пеп8 грит что длина строки должна быть не более 80 символов" - к счастью, времена 12-дюймовых мониторов уже давно прошли, и на эту рекомендацию можно смело забить. Сейчас де-факто ограничение, на которое стоит ориентироваться - 120 символов.